# Parse a Webservice Soap Return - PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I am using a Webservice Soap that returns a var_export/var_dump (not quite sure) of a PHP array. I need either convert the response into an actual php array or get the values of the specific array in [VALUE] as a list or xml: Formula, Aprueba, Describe, etc.

Thanks in advance!

```
      <getAttribDataResponse xmlns="urn:admin">
         <return>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CDATTRIBUTE] => 49
            [NMATTRIBUTE] => SD1-ACCION
            [FGDATATYPE] => 1
            [FGATTRIBUTETYPE] => 1
            [NMLABEL] => Doc_Acción de la Normativa
            [FGMULTIVALUED] => 1
            [VALUE] => Array
                (
                    [1721] => Formula
                    [1477] => Aprueba
                    [1486] => Describe
                    [1506] => Reglamenta
                    [1522] => Constituye
                    [2128] => Agrega
                    [1485] => Deroga
                    [1497] => Oficializa                  
                )

        )

)</return>
      </getAttribDataResponse>
```

Comment: That's the actual returned "data" from a call? (Looks like `print_r()` btw) Wow. I'd call that a debug printout at the most.

Comment: Anyway, if that's the case.. One regexp to extract the contents of VALUE, and then another regexp that extracts all the lines in the contents.

Comment: I would ask the owner of the webservice to return the data in a machine readable format like json e.g. `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: This may help https://github.com/simivar/reverse-print-r

Comment: Thanks both of you

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo, would you mind helping me out with a possible regexp to solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Andrew8902 Done. Did it answer your question?

Comment: It did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we go, the regexp route. In general though, if there's a package that can parse the data that I'm working on I'd try to use it instead.

```
// Copied straight off from <return> in the response,
// shortened for readability
$str = 'Array
(
    [0] => Array
    ...

)';

// 1st regexp to extract the content lines of [VALUE]
preg_match(
    '/\[VALUE\] => Array[^\(]*\(\s*\n([^\)]+)\n\s+\)\n/',
    $str,
    $matches
);

// $matches[0] is what matched the whole regexp,
// $matches[1].. is for any parentheses inside it.
// We want the contents of the 1st parenthesis, so $matches[1]
$value_contents = $matches[1];

// 2nd regexp to extract the key/value pairs of [VALUE]
// One parenthesis for the key and one for the value,
// so $macthes[1] and $matches[2]
preg_match_all(
    '/\[([^\]]+)\] => (.+)/',
    $value_contents,
    $matches
);
```

In this case we get this:

```
print_r($matches);
//    Array
//    (
//        [0] => Array
//            (
//                [0] => [1721] => Formula
//                [1] => [1477] => Aprueba
//                ...
//            )

//        [1] => Array
//            (
//                [0] => 1721
//                [1] => 1477
//                ...
//            )

//        [2] => Array
//            (
//                [0] => Formula
//                [1] => Aprueba
//                ...
//            )
//    )
```